# Unknown language identification

Tags: colors, tags

I'm currently working with a dead network application that received packets for a chat.

I checked that it received text like this one:

`hi there! {c:0000FF}foo{/c} sentence`

I have checked but have not found the language that uses that color syntax. It is some famous language or it's surely a self made script/library?

Original application used c++ and python as developping languages.

Thanks you all in advance,
Rag.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Do you want to know what markup language the snippet is using? If so consider posting a larger snippet. If you are asking what languages use 0000FF (RGB hexadecimal) style colours - well HTML is the most common one!

Comment: Do you need to parse these results, are you debugging? If you see the packets then just determine the syntax. It seems that it shouldn't be too hard. {c:xxx}...{/c} is like <c value=xxx>...</c>

Comment: i want to know what language or lib could use the "{c:hex}data{/c}" snippet. Of course, RGB is well know :P.

I am not debugging, i got the packets, which are not encrypted but seem to be serialized (just packed as a block), so i ask about the tags to search the unserialize in the same lang ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to prove a negative, but I'll wager it's a proprietary ('self made') syntax.